# React-native app with expokit crash on android release build

Tags: react-native, expo

Application is created with expo and detached to expokit. I'm using expoKit version 27.
It crashes only on first install, after refreshing app works as expected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUbRQ.png

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a late answer, but the correct workaround is here such that you have to run the Javascript packager first with the command `expo start`, after that you can start building with Android Studio.